# Does SearchControls.setTimeLimit() handle read timeout?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I'm having an issue where an `LdapContext.search()` against a directory will occasionally hang forever.  I tried supplying a `SearchControls` object for which I've called `setTimeLimit(10000),` but the issue still happens.

Given this, my thought now is that the SearchControls object is being used only as an advisory to the server and won't arrange a timeout on the client side read if no packets come back.  I looked around but didn't find any wording in the class documentation to explicitly confirm this.

Can anyone confirm my guess that SearchControls will not arrange a client side read timeout, and whether I should instead be using `com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout` to protect my client in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right.  SearchControls.setTimeLimit () doesn't control socket read timeout. See more at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/readtimeout.html